# Disaster Recovery of ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken, disaster-recovery

I was trying to test disaster recovery for my application using traffic manager and app services from Azure, but when my application switches across the region, **getting an error from MVC antiforgeryToken validator**.

*The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.*

How can I overcome this issue to achieve disaster recovery to be worked at any point of failure

Comment: The error message clearly states how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In your `web.config` try changing the `validationKey` property not to be auto-generated and specify a key instead.

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />
```

You can use this online tool for generating keys:
[All KeysGenerator](http://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx)

As @bradbury9 mentioned, for production, you should better generate your own key on IIS manager [Details Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager/).

Comment: I would never use online generators for machine keys, there is no way to know if those tools leak those keys. Its much better doing it yourself via the IIS manager. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager/